# Difference Between PID Temperature Controller Operating Modes?

Tags: heat, solid-state-relay, pid-controller, resistive-load

I am in the planning phase of an electric furnace project for metal casting. It's a hobby project for me. Most resources I've found online suggest to use a PID Temperature Controller in combination with a Solid State Relay for the temperature control of Nichrome or Kanthal resistance wire.

Now, from the reading I've done on PID controllers, there seem to be different ways to configure a PID controller's output operation. PID controllers from OMRON, for example, may use "on / off" control or "PID" control.

My questions are these:

- What is the difference between "on / off" mode and "PID" mode?
- What hardware needs to be used in combination with "on / off" mode vs "PID" mode? Is a Solid State Relay used in both cases?

I'm not sure that it matters for this particular question, but I'm planning on using AC at 120 Volts and somewhere between 10 and 15 Amps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On-off means the element turns on until the desired temperature is reached, and then off. When the temperature falls below the setpoint again, the heat turns back on.

In practice you don't want the system to rapidly toggle on and off right at the setpoint, so you would heat until 1 degree OVER the setpoint, and then not turn on the heater again until the temp falls 1 degree UNDER. That's called hysteresis. 1 degree is just an example, it can be 2 or 10 or whatever. This is the simplest control loop and what you should use unless you have a reason not to.

PID control basically produces an output "throttle" percentage from 0 to 100. It has 3 factors and needs to be tuned. This can be done manually, or some controllers have an auto-tune function. Your heater doesn't actually have a throttle input. It's just on or off, so what the controller will do is turn the heat on and off in a pattern to produce the desired output. For example, for 10% it might turn on for 1 second, then off for 9; the timebase is usually configurable. Some controllers have what's called "PWM" output, this is basically the same thing, but at a much higher frequency (kHz). Your SSR will not work well with that.

The advantage of PID is that it can keep the temperature right at the setpoint if it's well tuned. The disadvantage is that it's way more complicated and prone to problems.

For most applications I find that a degree or 2 of error is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I am planning to use a Raspberry Pi in place of a PID so I can build a web interface for controling setpoints and whatnot. 
Now that you explained the on / off style being good enough, I am comfortable moving forward with this plan.

Comment: As an alternative to simple on / off, is there any style of relay or controller (SCR, TRIAC, etc) capable of reducing the current available to a heating element so that a heating element could stay permanently on but at a lower power level in order to maintain the set temperature? I think this would effectively be utilizing a "throttle percentage" like you described. Maybe in the end the same result can be obtained using on / off but I'm curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: The Raspi is not my first choice for such an application. Major issue is reliability. My suggestion would be to use an Omron or similar controller built for purpose and use one that has modbus or other known protocol and have the raspi talk to it. Ensure you have adequate protection for overtemp etc as electronics do fail and you don’t want a failure to burn your house down.

Comment: @Kartman Agreed. Unless the furnace (and surroundings) can withstand it being on 100% indefinitely you need a failsafe such as a thermal fuse.

Comment: A microcontroller will be much better for temp control if you want to go the diy controller route. Considering you want a web interface I would use a ESP32, or an arduino which talks to a raspberry pi. Using an operating system for real time control is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Schmidty15 Yes there are circuits which can throttle the heater and not just cycle it on and off. However it's more complicated, and there's likely no advantage for your application.

Comment: @Schmidty15 This is not directly possible with a heating element. What you can do is turn it on and off very quickly or less quickly, i.e. PWM. (For a heater you probably don't notice the difference between anything faster than 20Hz. Motors or speakers or LEDs can use higher PWM frequencies. High frequencies require a DC supply and control with a transistor, but low frequencies like 10-20Hz may work fine with AC)

Comment: Thanks everyone!